# Spring Batch append common batch step at jobs in execution context whose name contains "abc"

Tags: spring-batch

I would like to know if there is way to consolidate a common spring batch step which is executed at the end of most of my batch jobs.

I know about abstract job but it only let me prepend step not append steps. I would like to see if there is any easy way short of me doing some fancy ApllicationContextAware and then extracting all batch jobs and appending common step to all of them.

Hopefully there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to perform some activity at the end of most jobs.
In that case, you may use a Job Execution Listener.
The `afterJob()` method is always executed and you can have your processing there. Use the same listener for multiple jobs.
[This](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html#interceptingJobExecution) link will give you an idea.

Comment: That is a good idea. I am familiar with the concepts of Job Listener, however I was looking for some kind of XML based solution. But anyway thanks for a nice suggestion.

Comment: Actually I need to invoke a common step - not do any activity. That step is invoked remotely and it is in my application context. Currently many jobs invoke that step by just having a last step inheriting from that step.